"error: Unable to find a compatible Visual Studio installation" when running 'setup.py' file to compile '.pyx' file
Long story short, I wrote a function creates a .pyx file then create a setup.py file  to compile the .pyx file to a .pyd file.
This is what the setup.py file looks like (self.new_file is the path to the .pyx file)
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='{self.command}',
    ext_modules=cythonize("{self.new_file}"),
)

I checked the file, and it's all correct. I also have another function which runs py setup.py build_ext --inplace. But when it runs, I get this:
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\PATH\TO\testFunc.pyx
running build_ext
building 'testFunc' extension
error: Unable to find a compatible Visual Studio installation.

I tried running the command myself and got the same error. I tried everything to get this to work. I tried to repair Visual Studio Build Tools, I ensured I had the Python development and Desktop development with C++ workloads were installed, I ensured I had cl.exe and other VS paths were in my PATH environment variables, I checked that they were all discoverable in my terminal. Nothing has worked. I keep getting the same error every time. I'm not quite sure what to do anymore. Please help 
Thanks
What I tried:
I tried to repair Visual Studio Build Tools, I ensured I had the Python development and Desktop development with C++ workloads were installed, I ensured I had cl.exe and other VS paths were in my PATH environment variables, I checked that they were all discoverable in my terminal.
What I expected to happen:
For my setup.py to compile my .pyx file to a .pyd file
What actually happened:
got "error: Unable to find a compatible Visual Studio installation."
